# Add CircularProgressIndicator to a button without increasing its height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use a `CircularProgressIndicator` inside a `Button` next to a `Text`.
This is how my button looks like with only text:

```
Button(
    onClick = { }
) {
    Row() {
        Text("Some action")
    }
}
```

[image]

As soon as I add the `CircularProgressIndicator`, my button gets much taller (higher):

```
Button(
    onClick = {  }
) {
    Row() {
        CircularProgressIndicator(color = Color.White)
        Text("Some action")
    }
}
```

[image]

So, how can I add a `CircularProgressIndicator` to my `Button` while keeping the initial `Button` height?

Comment: try  `Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically)` this will center the circular progress and text . you can provide the height and width for your components via modifier. Your components have default height so you can provide the height yourself as per your needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With **ButtonDefaults** you can easily fix the button height. Also for **CircularProgressIndicator** I added fixed size from **ButtonDefaults.IconSize**

```
var loading by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

Button(
    onClick = { loading = !loading },
    modifier = Modifier.height(ButtonDefaults.MinHeight).align(Alignment.Center)
) {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        if (loading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                color = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier.size(ButtonDefaults.IconSize),
                strokeWidth = 2.dp
            )
        }
        Text("Some action")
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: great example as it includes also strokeWidth etc. Thank you! Hint: Instead of `Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)` one can also use `Arrangement.spacedBy(ButtonDefaults.IconSpacing)` :-)